# if statement including "or" in Swift

Tags: swift, if-statement

I'm writing a bunch of if statements like this:

```
if thing == "A" { do something}
if thing == "C" { do something}
```

if I want "A" and "C" to do the same thing, is there a way to say

```
if thing == "A" or "C" { do something }
```

?

I'm just trying to clean things up instead of writing out every instance.

Thanks!!

Comment: For simple syntax questions like this I'd really suggest getting Apple's Swift book from the iTunes book store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming Swift.

You can't do anything like:

```
if thing == "A" or "C" { do something }
```

but you can do:

```
if thing == "A" || thing == "C" {
    do something
}
```

or you can do:

```
if ["A", "C"].contains(thing) {
    do something
}
```

or you can do:

```
switch thing {
case "A", "C":
    do something
default:
    break;
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Glad to help. In the future, please tag your question clearly. We were able to guess you meant Swift based on the iOS tag but it wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Swift: `if thing == "A" || thing == "C" { do something }`

Answer (score 0):

Above solutions are great but I generally prefer swift provided powerful Switch case statement to be in more Swift pattern. 
Define Thing as enum and do something like below:

```
let thing = Thing.A
    switch thing{
        case .A, .B:
            do something
        case .C:
            print("C")
        default:
            println("default")
    }
```

Comment: How does this improve on the existing answers? My answer already shows how to use a `switch`.